# magento 2 strange issue

Tags: magento2

Installed extension vsourz-html-sitemap
And executed

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I am getting this strange issue .

```
            Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getEntityPkName() must be an instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat given, called in /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 1369 and defined in /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:1532 Stack trace: #0 /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1369): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->getEntityPkName(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat)) #1 /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1476): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_addAttributeJoin('status', 'inner') #2 /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-c in /home/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php on line 1532
```

Even compiled and cleaned the cache.

When I comment out addAttributeToFilter code section in both two method 
then code run perfectly but with these filters are not function with magento 2?
or any other way to add filters?

```
public function getProductsAllCollection()
{
    $this->_productsCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->_productsCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name')
    ->setPageSize(0)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            ['attribute'=> 'status','eq' => 1]
        ]
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            [
                'attribute'=> 'visibility',
                'in' => [
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
    return $this->_productsCollection;
}

public function getProductsCollection($char)
{
    $this->_productsCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->_productsCollection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name')
    ->setPageSize(0)
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            ['attribute'=> 'status','eq' => 1]
        ]
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            [
                'attribute'=> 'visibility',
                'in' => [
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
    if ($char == '#') {
        $this->_productsCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute'=> 'name','regexp' => '^[^a-zA-Z]']
            ]
        );
    } else {
        $this->_productsCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute'=> 'name','like' => $char.'%']
            ]
        );
    }

    return $this->_productsCollection;
}
```

Comment: Because you are applying addAttributeToFilter in wrong way.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal  Please share some solution

Answer (score 1):

Disable the flat catalog to get the product collection. This extension is not compatible with flat catalog.

Comment: vsourz hot deals have same issue.I just disable the flat catalog and its working well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use old version of the extension. Download latest extension from their website Magenticity

https://www.magenticity.com/html-sitemap-magento2.html